# Python Not Showing in Command Line

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I installed Python as administrator and checked the box to add it to PATH. I then located Python.exe in my file explorer and copy/pasted the path and manually added this to my path variable as well... no luck. Python still doesnt show up when i use Sublime or the Command line.. Any ideas why?

Sublime Text Error:
`Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: ms-windows-store://pdp/?productid=9NJ46SX7X90P[Finished in 0.5s]`

Command line does not show anything:

```
C:\Users\xxx>python --version

C:\Users\xxxx>
```

System Variable:
Path -- C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.8

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding a Path variable to user variables, append the python path to the existing Path variable in System variables

Comment: Just added "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe" to the existing system variable with no luck.... thoughts?

Comment: Try running `python3 --version`

Comment: `python.exe` isn't to be included in the path. Change it to just `"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\"`. The path tells your OS _which directories_ to look in. For obvious reasons, `python.exe` is not a directory

Comment: No, change it to just `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38`.

Comment: Still no luck with removing the python.exe portion... And python3 --version returns nothing as well